# Complex Ingress Nginx Config(Nginx Ingress maintained by Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

We have a microservices architecture. We are planning to move this to Kubernetes cluster with Docker as container Runtime.(On Premise, No cloud)

Now I am able to figure out everything but one thing is not clear. 
Basically we have around 10 aggregators which we have exposed via Nginx. So we are planning to Use Nginx Ingress(Project which is maintained by Kubernetes).

My doubt is currently we have complex Nginx config like different log files for different domains, generate custom headers, using Nginx Caching with purging logic with Persistent Volumes etc. Currently, we have 5-6 config files for Nginx.

Is it all possible via Ingress? From what I have read, we cant directly provide Nginx conf, we have to provide all config via ingress only? Also is it possible to break the ingress config in multiple files?

If yes, can someone provide some reference?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have to have an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers) to satisfy an Ingress. Only creating an Ingress resource has no effect. In your case you need to deploy an Ingress controller such as [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

You can have multiple ingress rules for the same hostname with different paths. You can spread the Ingress configuration for a common host across multiple Ingress resources using Mergeable Ingress resources. Such resources can belong to the  *same*  or  *different*  namespaces. This enables easier management when using a large number of paths. See the  [Mergeable Ingress Resources](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.7.1/examples/mergeable-ingress-types)  example on our GitHub.

As an alternative to Mergeable Ingress resources, you can use  [VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute resources](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/virtualserver-and-virtualserverroute-resources)  for cross-namespace configuration. See the  [Cross-Namespace Configuration](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.7.1/examples-of-custom-resources/cross-namespace-configuration)  example on our GitHub.

Take a look: [cross-namespace-configuration/](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/cross-namespace-configuration/), [ingress-controller-configmap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have already deployed ingress-nginx. My doubt is basically we have complex Nginx conf, can we do that with ingress-nginx controller or not?

Comment: I would say that it is better to split this file. Please take a look: https://serverfault.com/questions/499337/how-can-i-combine-similar-configuration-info-of-server-blocks-in-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/